# Actions with multple objects, and general animations

Tags: animation, actions

I'm making a long animation, and was annoyed by how messy it got, then I learned about the NLE editor, and actions, which sounded super cool. However, now when I try to split my animations up in actions, I run into the issue that I can't animate multiple objects into one Action. I have an empty, with a camera as child. Both objects are part of one animation, but how do I animate them in one action? I tried baking but that doesn't seem to work (so far)

Also, what is the best way to animate in blender without it getting messy? I can't imagine blender movies are made with just a million random keyframes in a timeline.

My camera rigs I am trying to turn into actions: [image]

Comment: "how do I animate them in one action?" What do you mean exactly? If they are 2 separate objects, you can't merge their actions into one. You can always synchronize their action in the NLA though. Also, I doubt you can have million random keyframes, you rarely need one keyframe per frame, as most of the time you use the interpolations from keyframe 1 to keyframe 2